# I am trying to render an image after looping through a list of arrays of objects

Tags: reactjs, image, rendering

I am looping through an array which is a lists of objects. In the objects, I have information about a phone such as: title, info, img, company etc...

When I first looped through the array, I was able to get all the details including the images and rendered on the screen. I then set a link for each of the list and when you click on it, it takes you to the product details component which displays all the information about that product.

The problem I am facing now is,in the ProductDetails component, I am able to get all the information contained in the objects and render them on the screen except the image.

Why is the image not rendering in the ProductDetails component?

Am I doing anything wrong? Below is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { storeProducts } from "./data";

const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    storeProducts.map((product) => {
      return product.title === match.params.id ? setProducts(product) : null;
    });
  }, []);

  const { img, title, info } = products;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <p>{title}</p>
        <img src={img} alt={title} />
        <p>{info}</p>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure destructed `img` property contains value?

You can `console.log(img)` after destructuring

Apart from that I think its better to select product on `UseEffect` this way...

```js
 useEffect(() => {
  const product = storeProducts.find((product) => product.title === match.params.id);
  setProducts(product);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Whe I console log image, it first prints undefined before the value.

Comment: Looks like its either the wrong property name or it happens product doesnt have an image